# How to stop blender from recalculating normals?

Tags: shaders, normals

I have a mesh (a rock wall) that I would like to split into pieces and export each piece for a game engine.  The mesh has a smooth, undulating surface and when all the sections are merged into a single mesh, it looks the way I want it to.  However, when I split the mesh into pieces, Blender recalculates the normals along the edges causing a very visible change in shading.

I would like Bender to leave the normals alone, or maybe give me some way to edit the normals manually.  Can I do this?

Comment: You need to use custom normals. It's the only way to preserve the smooth shading on the edges you split.

Comment: How do you use custom normals?  I tired adding a normal edit modifier to my mesh.  Not only does it automatically recalculate my normals to cause a 'radial' effect, but if I split my mesh it still recalculates again along the new seam.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Blender **add-on** for this exact purpose called [TiNA](https://gitlab.com/Modanung/TiNA) which allows you to easily transfer normals between objects. TiNA basically turns the somewhat overwhelming [Data Transfer Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) into a set of more comprehensible operations.
There's a [special branch](https://gitlab.com/Modanung/TiNA/tree/b2.80) for those using Blender 2.80 beta.

[image: TiNA|]

```
 Hotkey           | Operation 
------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Alt+N            | Transfer Normals from selection to active object
 Shift+Alt+N      | Transfer Normals from active object to all other selected objects
 Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N | Clear Custom Normals data for entire selection
 Alt+W            | Wrap Normals
```

In your case you could transfer the normals from an unsplit duplicate by selecting all objects, and - with the unsplit duplicate as your active object - hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

[image: Example results]

Comment: maybe you need to detail the feature, usage, effect, or other information...??